# filter and set() in one stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

So I've some sample code I'm playing with to try and figure out this logic below.  It's just one large main method and two POJOs, but it'll run.  I'm debugging to get values at the point of termination.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        obj1 obj1 = new obj1();
        obj1 obj12 = new obj1();

        obj2 obj2 = new obj2();
        obj2 obj22 = new obj2();

        obj1.id = 123L;
        obj1.carId = 1234L;
        obj12.id = 123L;
        obj12.carId = 1234L;

        obj2.carId = 1234L;
        obj22.carId = 12345L;

        ArrayList<obj1> obj1Arr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<obj2> obj2Arr = new ArrayList<>();

        obj1Arr.add(obj1);
        obj1Arr.add(obj12);

        obj2Arr.add(obj2);
        obj2Arr.add(obj22);

        List<obj2> newCarList= obj2Arr.stream()
                .filter(anObjOf2 -> obj1Arr
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(carReg -> carReg.getCarId().equals(anObjOf2.getCarId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

POJO1:

```
public class obj1 {

    Long id = null;
    Long carId = null;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(Long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }
}
```

POJO2:

```
public class obj2 {

    Long id = null;
    Long carId = null;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(Long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm streaming and filtering out any `obj`s that don't match on `carId`.  My next goal is to then `set` `id` (not carId) on the matched object.

Basically, if `obj1.carId == obj2.carId` THEN `set obj1.id = obj2.id`.

My problem is I don't know how to do this in the same stream.  Is it possible?  I can't help but think there is a need for an iterator at this point?

Comment: Please elaborate this part of the question ... *set the corresponding id on the objs in obj2Arr.*

Comment: this is not clear for me `My next goal is to then set the corresponding id on the objs in obj2Arr.` and in stream you are filtering objects that has same `carid` in `obj1Arr`

Comment: I've updated it.. hope it's clear. Basically, `if obj1.carId == obj2.carId`  THEN `set obj1.id = obj2.id`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @notAChance no, because its already set..that's how you've been able to compare it..isn't it?

Comment: I think the confusion is coming from the over use of `id`.  `carId` and `id` are diferent.  I'm comparing on `carId`, when matched, I want `obj2.setId(obj1.getId());`

Comment: There is something incorrect(undetermined in question) that I could sense. **Scenario**: If there are 2 `obj1` with same `cardId` and 2 `obj2` with same `cardId` as well. Now you would always end up updating just 1 `obj1` in the former list for both the elements in the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest first creating a `Map` mapping `carId` to `id` for each element in the first list (I've modified your class a bit to make it more readable and removed duplicate IDs, which I assume were a mistake):

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class Car {
    Long id = null;
    Long carId = null;
}
List<Car> obj1Arr = Arrays.asList(new Car(1L, 123L), new Car(2L, 1234L));
List<Car> obj2Arr = Arrays.asList(new Car(0L, 1234L), new Car(0L, 12345L));

Map<Long, Long> carIdToId = obj1Arr.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getCarId, Car::getId));
// [Car(id=2, carId=1234), Car(id=0, carId=12345)]
```

Then you can use this `Map` to filter for cars with the same `carID` without having to compare with each other car. Then, use `forEach` just set the Id in the original list.

```
obj2Arr.stream()
        .filter(anObjOf2 -> carIdToId.containsKey(anObjOf2.getCarId()))
        .forEach(anObjOf2 -> anObjOf2.setId(carIdToId.get(anObjOf2.getCarId())));
System.out.println(obj2Arr);
// [Car(id=2, carId=1234), Car(id=0, carId=12345)]
```

If you want *only* the items with equal `carId`, you can set the ID in `peek` and then `collect`. This will still modify the original instances, though:

```
obj2Arr = obj2Arr.stream()
        .filter(anObjOf2 -> carIdToId.containsKey(anObjOf2.getCarId()))
        .peek(anObjOf2 -> anObjOf2.setId(carIdToId.get(anObjOf2.getCarId())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(obj2Arr);
// [Car(id=2, carId=1234)]
```

Or create a list of entirely new instances:

```
obj2Arr = obj2Arr.stream()
        .map(Car::getCarId)
        .filter(carIdToId::containsKey)
        .map(carId -> new Car(carIdToId.get(carId), carId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(obj2Arr);
// [Car(id=2, carId=1234)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this fits the bill perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do** these two operations in one stream. It's a really bad style.

Collect the data first. Then mutate the elements. Something like:

```
Map<obj2, Optional<obj1>> map = 
    obj2Arr.stream()
           .collect(toMap(identity(), o2 -> obj1Arr.stream()
                                                  .filter(o1 -> o1.getCarId().equals(o2.getCarId()))
                                                  .findAny()));

map.forEach((o1, optO2) -> optO2.ifPresent(o2 -> o1.setId(o2.id)));
```

Otherwise you can just use nested for-each loops.

Comment: Yes it seems `id` is being set arbitrarily to the next iterated item.

Comment: @notAChance Okay, I stand corrected. Check the updated answer.

Comment: `.filter(a -> a.getCarId().equals(o.getCarId()))` would be correct implementation of `filter`

Comment: Yes `::equals` doesn't work.  Thanks for the updates @ETO

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the Predicate `anyMatch`

```
List<obj2> newCarList= obj2Arr.stream()
            .filter(anObjOf2 -> obj1Arr
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(carReg ->  {
            if(carReg.getCarId().equals(anObjOf2.getCarId()))) {
                 carReg.setId(anObjOf2.getId());
                  return true;
               }
           return false;
     }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Second Approach**

Filtering first

```
List<obj2> newCarList= obj2Arr.stream()
            .filter(anObjOf2 -> obj1Arr
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(carReg -> carReg.getCarId().equals(anObjOf2.getCarId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now Set the id

```
newCarList.forEach(obj->{
           obj1Arr.forEach(o-> {
            if(o.getCarId().equals(obj.getCarId()) {
                  o.setId(obj.getId());
                }
           };
    });
```

Comment: I would rather suggest doing that in another iteration rather that mutating objects within a terminal operation.

Comment: Mutating data in a method that expects a pure predicate is poor style and will only cause problems down the road

Comment: @nullpointer this is what just crossed my mind.  So basically the answer is:  "yes it can be done, but should be done using a second iterator" ?

Comment: i agree but it seems to be double operation and also the operation is not on the stream object @nullpointer

Comment: @Deadpool you have indeed answered my question, which specifically asked for a solution "in one stream".  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If an **`O(m*n)`** solution works for you, then the simpler implementation would be using the `for` loop as:

```
// classes renamed for naming convention and relatiing to question at the same time 
List<ObjectTwo> newCarList = new ArrayList<>();
for(ObjectTwo objectTwo: objectTwoArr) {
    for (ObjectOne objectOne : objectOneArr) {
        if (objectTwo.getCarId().equals(objectOne.getCarId())) {
            objectOne.setId(objectTwo.getId());
            newCarList.add(objectTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

`m` and `n` being the respective sizes of the lists.

Comment: This is letter by letter identical to my current solution.  Unfortunately my pull request reviewer is a Java 8 fetishist.

Comment: @notAChance I've got a doubt while trying things out. There is something incorrect(undetermined in question) that I could sense.
**Scenario**: If there are 2 `obj1` and 2 `obj2` with same `cardId` as well. Now you would always end up updating just 1 `obj1` in the former list for both the elements in the latter.

Comment: this is true, but in my real world code it is safe to assume there will be no duplicate id's.  All id's will always be unique to each object.  Both lists are populated from same entity, one is persisted and given `id`, other is not.  Other list is then converted, during which some objects may be dropped.  This leads to the need for matching, as we need persisted `id` on other object. Good thinking though.

Comment: *some objects may be dropped.* ideally means, all the items existing here would still be present in the other list there is just the mapping required there to fill in added `id`.